# Exiting Android App: back vs recent apps-->close

Tags: android, android-memory

I thought [pressing back until your app screens are gone] and [pressing the square hardware button for recent apps, then closing the app] did the same thing.  However I think i see a difference in my app when performing these 2 different actions.  Do both close the app and remove it from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do both close the app and remove it from memory?

No. Pressing BACK N times destroys N activities. It has no direct effect at all on your process, [which will remain running for a time](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). Swiping your task off of the overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list) will terminate your process.

Comment: thanks.  does this mean you can finish() all activities, but to truly close your app you must close it in the application context?  how would you do this?

Comment: @user3148156: "but to truly close your app you must close it in the application context?" -- app developers do not "truly close [their] app". App developers let Android cache the process for a while, to make it faster for the user to get back into the app. App developers then let Android terminate the process when needed to free up system RAM for other apps.